# VS Code Keyboard Shortcut for "flutter pub run build_runner watch --delete-conflicting-outputs "

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, code-generation

Is there a possibility to run this command via a shortcut in vs code?
Seems unnecessary work to type the command `flutter pub run build_runner watch --delete-conflicting-outputs` by myself every single time.

Context: This command is used for code generation in flutter and dart projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Inside vs code press Ctrl + Shift + B / Cmd + Option + B on MacOS.
2. This popup appears
   [image: vs code popup with build_runner commands]
3. Click the settings icon to the right of the `watch` command which opens the `tasks.json`
4. Append  `--delete-conflicting-outputs` to the command
   [image: tasks.json]
5. Pressing Ctrl + Shift + B again now opens a popup with the full command
   [image: vs code popup with build_runner commands including the changed command]